# Word that describes something purposefully unrelated to a theme

Tags: meaning, synonyms, word-usage

In my efforts to come up with a bowling team name for the upcoming season, I've found myself gravitating toward names that are totally unrelated to the normal bowling theme that most teams go for. For example, team names that fit the common theme are:

- "We Three Strikes"
- "Gutterballs"
- "Ball for One, One for Ball"

Whereas this year I want to suggest something like:

- "Squirrels"
- "Trees"
- "Mass Transit System"
- "Comfy Shoes"

There has to be a word that describes the type of name I'm looking for. Something similar to irreverent maybe, but that implies disrespect which I don't believe this team name would be. I can feel a word buzzing around my head but I can't pluck it out of there.

Comment: perhaps "whimsical".

Comment: You've already used the perfect word: **unrelated**. Words like *random* do not disallow related terms, which seems to be your desire.

Comment: Something feels missing from **unrelated** however, I don't think it conveys that it was purposely done to deviate from the theme, allowing for the accidental. That could just be me overthinking.

Comment: 'Left-field' may be appropriate. How appropriate depends on what type of bowling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be looking for **non sequitur**:

> non sequitur (noun) |  non se·qui·tur \ˌnän-ˈse-kwə-tər also -ˌtu̇r\
>
> A statement (such as a response) that does not follow logically from or is not clearly related to anything previously said.
>
> A conversational and literary device, often used for comedic purposes. It is something said that, because of its apparent lack of meaning relative to what preceded it, seems absurd to the point of being humorous or confusing.

**Example**

*What's the name of their bowling team? The "Honey Glazed Hockey Sticks"? What a total non sequitur!*

**Sources:**

1. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur
2. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_sequitur_(literary_device)

Answer (score -3):

Names that are unrelated to the bowling theme are **random.**